# Reordering and Dragging adorners are not visible inside the Flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8.1

I just tested the ListView control in Windows 8.1 for my Windows Store application. I really like the Reordering and Dragging of Items in the ListView and it is obviously required to use inside the Flyout for my application.

Unfortunately i get some problem with the Dragging and ReOrdering of ListView items when i use inside the Flyout. Begin with, Dragging of Items are working fine as expected in the normal display. If i use inside of Flyout, Dragging adorner is not visible over the Flyout and instead it comes beneath the Flyout.

I have attached the screenshots in the normal and Flyout display.

[image]

[image]

Sample has been attached in the below SkyDrive link. It would be helpful to you guys to grasp more information about the problem.

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=89346CF5C45CEB8C&resid=89346CF5C45CEB8C%212942&authkey=APwj9svhnGFMqwY

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be a satisfying answer. I have been struggling with the same issue for a while now. I decided to move the reordering to the top AppBar only to discover that the same issue shows up there too.

I found an existing question on msdn and added my own comment and according to a Microsoft employee this is not a bug but a feature:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c1add91a-e887-4d08-a3f8-884ec22239f6/dragged-gridview-item-is-not-visible-when-it-is-dragged-over-appbar

As for a solution:

1. You can change your design and move the reordering out of the settings flyout into the main screen.
2. You make your own flyout / top application bar control.